# Get value from hashmap by key which is ENUM in EL

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, enums, el

I have an enum like

```
public enum InventoryStatus {
        IN_USE,
        RE_USED,
        STOCK_OLD, 
        STOCK_NEW, 
        SCRAPPED
}
```

and a HashMap having values like (say came from db)

```
 Map<InventoryStatus, Long> statusMap = new HashMap<InventoryStatus, Long>
{IN_USE=3, SCRAPPED=2, RE_USED=2, STOCK_NEW=2}
```

so now what I wanted is, I need to get value using key(which is of type enumeration)

something like

```
<td>${statusMap[inventoryStatus.STOCK_NEW]}</td> //not correct throwing numberformat exception
```

where statusMap is hashmap attribute, inventoryStatus is an enum which I added in controller

```
model.addAttribute("statusMap", statusMap);
model.addAttribute("inventoryStatus", InventoryStatus.values());
```

I having trouble in manipulating enum in map in jstl
so, please someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `inventoryStatus` is `InventoryStatus[]`, as you defined in your model:

```
model.addAttribute("inventoryStatus", InventoryStatus.values());
```

But you used this model attribute as it's a `InventoryStatus` instance here:

```
<td>${statusMap[inventoryStatus.STOCK_NEW]}</td>
```

Instead you should write something like this:

```
<td>${statusMap[inventoryStatus[3]}</td>
```

*Because `inventoryStatus` is an array of `InventoryStatus`*.

Comment: Yeah, this answer seems good. But my doubt is will that sequence/order will always be same. Because we can't depend just on numbers right.

Answer (score 0):

this solution is helpful for those who want to check for one or two enum values

```
<c:forEach items="${inventoryStatus}" var="status">
    <c:if test="${status == 'STOCK_NEW'} ">
        <td>${statusMap[status] eq null ? 0 : statusMap[status]}</td></c:if>
</c:forEach>

<c:forEach items="${inventoryStatus}" var="status">
    <c:if test="${status == 'IN_USE'} ">
        <td>${statusMap[status] eq null ? 0 : statusMap[status]}</td></c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

But it will be a bad code if we want to check for all available enum values.

Is there anyway check for key and get value without these many for loops and if cases.